# Obfuscator settings

Tags: obfuscar

Why this settings for Obfuscator do not obfuscate private methods of public classes?

```
  <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="true" />
  <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />
```

in Reflector it looks like:

```
private void A(MarketDataEventArgs args1)
{
    if ((args1.get_MarketDataType() == null) && (this.A != args1.get_Price()))
    {
        this.A = args1.get_Price();
   ...
```

Comment: That's already obfuscated. What do you expect? See nothing at all in Reflector?

Comment: Hi!

What does Obfuscar do?
https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=What%20It%20Does&referringTitle=Documentation

I think this example has "some" source code changes after decompiling

Comment: Looked up close. The tool works correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Scatophaga/Comparison_of_.NET_obfuscators It seems that you need to better learn what is obfuscation.